# How to convert a Python library from Python2 to Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a code using "PyOPC" library (https://github.com/ibh-systems/pyopc). I fixed all the `print` statements by adding `()` at the starting and ending.

But when I install the library, I am getting more errors.

Such as:

```
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyOPC-0.1-py3.7.egg\PyOPC\servers\esdsrv.py", line 90
    def Read(self,(IPH,inOptions,outOptions)):
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax



  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyOPC-0.1-py3.7.egg\PyOPC\utils.py", line 313
    def print_options((ilist,Options)):
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyOPC-0.1-py3.7.egg\PyOPC\XDAClient.py", line 46
    except ZSI.FaultException, z:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyOPC-0.1-py3.7.egg\PyOPC\OPCContainers.py", line 257
    raise AttributeError,'Unknown complex type %s for filling'%buf
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any easy way to fix them? I listed down four main errors, can someone tell me the correct syntax in Python3?

Comment: Were you able to successful convert it over to Python3?  Of course, it comes with the ZSI and other libraries that need conversion as well.

Answer (score 3):

Parameter unpacking has been removed... things like

```
def foo(x, (y, z)):
    ...
```

should be changed to

```
def foo(x, _yz):
    (y, z) = _yz
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

This online tool may help https://www.pythonconverter.com/
which is based on https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

Edit:

**Some Changes**

1) print function syntax has been changed from `print "Message"` to `print("Message")` 
2) `xrange` is replaced with `range`
3) Exception raising syntax was `raise IOError, "file error"` is now `raise IOError("file error")`
4) Exception Handling was

```py
except NameError, err:
    print err, '--> our error message'
```

is now

```py
except NameError as err:
    print(err, '--> our error message')
```

5) `my_generator.next()` is replaced with `next(my_generator)`
6) `input()` now always returns a string

more changes can be found on https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html

Answer (score 1):

```
def Read(self,IPH_and_inOptions_and_outOptions):
except ZSI.FaultException as z:
raise AttributeError('Unknown complex type %s for filling'%buf)
```